# smarty add a counter and check the values and add class

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

In smarty I want to set a counter value and check it's increment. In simple php the code is  like this

```
$i = 0;
while ( $someValues ) :
$i++;
<div class="test ''.$class.">$number</div>
endwhile;
```

Now in php I want to add class like this

```
if($i==1) {
    $class= 'active';
  }
  else {
    $class= '';
  }
```

In smarty I have the all the values from the database has been assigned to the variable someValues.
so here in smarty I will check that like

```
{foreach from=$someValues item=row}
<div class="test">$row.number</div>
{foreach}
```

here its giving the result like this

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
```

Now here I want the same type of counter and want to add class. So can someone tell me how to do this?
I had tried while loop to check but it showed the total page blank.

Answer (score 1):

indexes from 1 you have in

```
{$smarty.foreach.name.iteration}
```

If you want to add class to the first div in foreach, you can simply use

```
<div class="test{if $smarty.foreach.name.first} first{/if}">text</div>
or
<div class="test{if $smarty.foreach.name.index == 0} first{/if}">text</div>
or
<div class="test{if $smarty.foreach.name.iteration == 1} first{/if}">text</div>
```

EDIT:
More info: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl